# Keychain SecItemAdd A required entitlement isn't present

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I am trying to add a certificate(base64) which was extracted from .mobileconfig file to the shared keychain: $(TeamIdentifierPrefix)com.apple.networkextensionsharing as mentioned in the `[NEHotspotEAPSettings][1]`. I have enabled the keychain sharing and added $(TeamIdentifierPrefix)com.apple.networkextensionsharing to the entitlements.
[image]

and this is how my provisioning profile looks with entitlements:

[image]

This is how I am adding the cert

```
NSString *cert = @""Y2VydC5jb20xIDAeBgNVBAMTF0RpZ2lDZXJ0IEdsb2JhbCBSb290"
    "IENBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMI...";

NSData *certData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:cert options:0];
SecCertificateRef certRef = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFDataRef)certData);

NSDictionary* addquery = @{ (id)kSecValueRef:   (__bridge id)certRef,
                                (id)kSecClass:      (id)kSecClassCertificate,
                                (id)kSecAttrAccessGroup: @"123XYZ.com​.apple​.networkextensionsharing";
                         };

OSStatus status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)addquery, NULL);
    if (status != errSecSuccess) {
        // Handle the error
    }
```

I am getting following error while adding the cert to the keychain:

> errSecMissingEntitlement                 = -34018,    /* A required
>   entitlement isn't present. */

Can anyone help me point out where I am doing it wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, one should use automatic signing with which entitlements are added automatically. There is no way to add the entitlement in provisioning profile